# My Entity Framework Core & ASP.NET Core MVC app connection string doesn't update automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I'll start by saying I know very little about web apps and such so this may seem really basic, but I can't find a clear answer so far.

I have put together a simple Entity Framework Core, ASP.NET Core MVC app that uses a SQL Server database and it launches and work on my local test machine.  When I publish to Azure, (and create the resources and db) the connection string is not automatically redirected to the database on azure.

If I manually switch it to the azure string it all works.

How do I configure the project so that when I publish I don't have to manually change the connection string?

My application has a `appsettings.json` file, where I've manually entered my connection string(s).. e.g...

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "local_abpwebtestdb": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Company.metrics.db1;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "abpwebtestdb": "Server = tcp:companytestmetrics.database.windows.net,1433; Initial Catalog = postmetrics_db; Persist Security Info = False; User ID = xxxxx; Password =xxxxxxx; MultipleActiveResultSets = False; Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = False; Connection Timeout = 30;"
  },
```

Then in my application I manually swap between these two lines:

```
// string con = Configuration.GetConnectionString("local_abpwebtestdb");
string con = Configuration.GetConnectionString("abpwebtestdb");
```

In the tutorials posted by MS they use a local db then when you publish it magically redirects to the new one on Azure.

How does the configuration work? (please pretend I have exactly no extended background knowledge here)

Thanks!
DR

Answer (score 0):

If this is a .net core MVC app the database should be configured in Startup.cs
as shown here [New Database MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio#code-try-6)

Add code to Startup.cs ConfigureServices it will look something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("abpwebtestdb")));
}
```

Now that the Db connection is correctly setup at startup you write a new constructor for your controllers that need a DB connection.

Like this:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

KnuturO - thanks for the reply!  After your comments I checked my settings again and found that the name of my connection string in the azure console / application settings page was "defaultconnection" - which seemed ok to me.. but not so.  Changing that to match the name of my connection string (e.g. abpwebtestdb ) did the trick.

Thanks for the push to look again and it is working now.

Regards,
DR